# How to fix ImportError: No module named 'telebot'

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, zabbix, python-telegram-bot

I'm configuring a bot to send alerts from Zabbix, so I installed Python and the modules:

```
sudo apt install python python-pip python-setuptools
```

After that, I installed the bot API to use on Zabbix:

```
python -m pip install --user pyTelegramBotAPI
```

Created the script in **/usr/lib/zabbix/alertscripts/** :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import telebot,sys

BOT_TOKEN='123TOKENAQUI321'
DESTINATION=sys.argv[1]
SUBJECT=sys.argv[2]
MESSAGE=sys.argv[3]

MESSAGE = MESSAGE.replace('/n','\n')
tb = telebot.TeleBot(BOT_TOKEN)
tb.send_message(DESTINATION,SUBJECT + '\n' + MESSAGE)
```

Changed permissions:

```
sudo chmod +x telegram

sudo chown -R zabbix telegram
```

And when testing the script on terminal or Zabbix the following error appears:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/zabbix/alertscripts/telegram", line 2, in 
>       import telebot,sys ImportError: No module named 'telebot'

I tried to solve by installing the module:

```
python -m pip install --user telebot
```

Installing the module did not solve it, so I tried to use python3, and the script on the terminal worked, but in Zabbix still showing the same error. I ended up going back to python.

The telebot module does not appear with `pip list`, only inside the python terminal using the  command `help ("modules")`.

Does anyone know that may be causing the problem?

Comment: are you using python3? Try using pip3 install instead of pip install.

Comment: I already tried with python3 and pip3, then it worked sending messages through the terminal, but in Zabbix still giving the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to solve it using `python3`, but this time I removed the other versions of `python` completely before installing again, the steps were as follows:

```
sudo python -m pip uninstall pyTelegramBotAPI
sudo apt remove python python-pip python-setuptools
sudo apt install python3 python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-six
sudo python3 -m pip install pyTelegramBotAPI six
sudo pip install six
```

Answer (score 1):

For like these errors, reinstall the library or use (--upgrade) when you install it!

like this:

```
pip uninstall telebot
pip install pyTelegramBotAPI
pip install pytelegrambotapi --upgrade
```